# Javascript Sencha cmd app build error occurred while executing this line

Tags: javascript, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I am trying to create a touch app using Cordova on a Mac. However when I  run this code `sencha app build native testing` I get this error:

```
Sencha Cmd v5.1.2.52
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : native
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Concatenating output to file /Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/build/temp/testing/thisApp/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js
[INF] writing content to /Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending content to /Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/bootstrap.json
[INF] merging 0 input resources into /Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/cordova/www/resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into /Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/cordova/www/resources
[INF] merging 14 input resources into /Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/cordova/www
[INF] merged 0 resources into /Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/cordova/www
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
identical ../css/app.css 
[INF] Copying page resources to /Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/cordova/www
[INF] Writing content to /Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/cordova/www/microloader.js
[INF] Appending content to /Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/cordova/www/microloader.js
[INF] Building output markup to /Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/cordova/www/index.html
[INF] Writing content to /Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/cordova/www/index.html
[INF] [Cordova] Cordova is adding platforms "ios"
[INF] [shellscript] npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-ios/3.8.0
[INF] [shellscript] TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters.
[INF] [shellscript]     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:73:11)
[INF] [shellscript]     at TunnelingAgent.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
[INF] [shellscript]     at TunnelingAgent.createSocket (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:117:25)
[INF] [shellscript]     at TunnelingAgent.createSecureSocket [as createSocket] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:184:41)
[INF] [shellscript]     at TunnelingAgent.addRequest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:80:8)
[INF] [shellscript]     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:154:16)
[INF] [shellscript]     at Object.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
[INF] [shellscript]     at Object.exports.request (https.js:136:15)
[INF] [shellscript]     at Request.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:594:30)
[INF] [shellscript]     at Request.end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/index.js:1186:28)
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:435: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:17: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/h/Documents/Dev/testing/thisApp/.sencha/app/cordova-impl.xml:144: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/Users/h/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.2.52/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:668: shellscript returned: 1
```

I'm using Sencha touch 2.4.1 and Sencha cmd 5.1.2.52, and am running these commands on a Mac. Any ideas what might be causing this error?

Thanks,

**EDIT:**

When I ran

`sudo sencha -debug app build native testing > error.txt` the only error I get is this:

```
    [ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/h/Documents/testDev/testApp/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:435: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/h/Documents/testDev/testApp/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:17: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/h/Documents/testDev/testApp/.sencha/app/cordova-impl.xml:144: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/Users/h/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.2.52/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:668: shellscript returned: 1
     at com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException.wrap(BasicException.java:54)
     at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.execute(AntScript.java:121)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.execute(PluginManager.java:93)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeReverseFirst(PluginManager.java:134)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:252)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:593)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands.java:92)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:329)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:43)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.dispatch(BasePluginCommands.java:148)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:73)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:141)
   Caused by: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/h/Documents/testDev/testApp/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:435: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/h/Documents/testDev/testApp/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:17: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/h/Documents/testDev/testApp/.sencha/app/cordova-impl.xml:144: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/Users/h/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.2.52/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:668: shellscript returned: 1
     at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.execute(AntScript.java:117)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.execute(PluginManager.java:93)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeReverseFirst(PluginManager.java:134)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:252)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:593)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands.java:92)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:329)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:43)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.dispatch(BasePluginCommands.java:148)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:73)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:141)
   Caused by: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/h/Documents/testDev/testApp/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:17: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/h/Documents/testDev/testApp/.sencha/app/cordova-impl.xml:144: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/Users/h/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.2.52/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:668: shellscript returned: 1
     at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
     at com.sencha.ant.CallTask.execute(CallTask.java:130)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.execute(AntScript.java:117)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.execute(PluginManager.java:93)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeReverseFirst(PluginManager.java:134)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:252)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:593)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands.java:92)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:329)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:43)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.dispatch(BasePluginCommands.java:148)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:73)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:141)
   Caused by: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/h/Documents/testDev/testApp/.sencha/app/cordova-impl.xml:144: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/Users/h/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.2.52/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:668: shellscript returned: 1
     at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
     at com.sencha.ant.CallTask.execute(CallTask.java:130)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
     at com.sencha.ant.CallTask.execute(CallTask.java:130)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.execute(AntScript.java:117)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.execute(PluginManager.java:93)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeReverseFirst(PluginManager.java:134)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:252)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:593)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands.java:92)
     at com.sencha.command.app.AppCommands$BuildCommand.execute(AppCommands.java:329)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:175)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:43)
     at com.sencha.command.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.dispatch(BasePluginCommands.java:148)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:64)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:73)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:141)
   Caused by: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/Users/h/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.2.52/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:668: shellscript returned: 1
     at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:401)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
     at com.sencha.ant.CallTask.execute(CallTask.java:130)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
     at com.sencha.ant.CallTask.execute(CallTask.java:130)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at 
   Caused by: shellscript returned: 1
```

Comment: Try to run it in debug mode and write output to a file.
sencha -debug app build native testing > log.txt

Comment: Just added the log file errors, see edit. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

I had to downgrade node.js to 10.25 in order for it to work. (I had 12.0, but also heard that 11.x doesn't work as well.)

Here are instructions how: http://www.websector.de/blog/2011/12/15/quick-tip-node-how-to-downgrade-node-js-on-os-x/

Comment: I have version 0.10.35 and trying to build an android version on Windows, should I still downgrade?

Comment: Not sure, but if you're getting the same error why not.

Comment: Instead of downgrading this way, consider using nvm to handle multiple Node version: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm