# sencha touch cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, ant, sencha-touch

I created a new app with sencha generate app command using sencha cmd 5.1.2.52,
then ran 'sencha cordova init' (with and without a name), then added a plugin, it was successfully added. Now while building the app with 'sencha app build native' it gives the following error.

> [ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sencha_start\pc2.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:435: The following e
>   rror occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sencha_start\pc2.sencha\app\packager-impl.xml:17: The following
>    error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sencha_start\pc2.sencha\app\cordova-impl.xml:144: The following
>    error occurred while executing this line:
>   jar:file:/C:/Users/Lenovo/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.2.52/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/ant
>   lib.xml:644: shellscript returned: 1

Comment: have you installed ant

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade your Node.js to 10.25 as suggested in this question: [Javascript Sencha cmd app build error occurred while executing this line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969207/)

Answer (score 0):

After adding the plugin(s), remove the platform and add it again. You'll have to run the commands from inside the cordova folder

Example of removing a platform:

```
cordova platform remove ios
```

Example of adding a platform:

```
cordova platform add ios
```

Comment: i did try that but it didn't work in case of ios, although i was able to get rid of the error for android

Comment: Could you tell me which version of cordova and cordova-android you are using?